# What is the name of this aditional tube of a siphon?

Tags: pipe

I need to make an adjust in the siphon of my kitchen sink.
I am trying to figure out what is the name of some types of siphon that have a thin (sometimes flexible) pipe before the water drain.

It is illustrated in this image:
[image]

Here do have four water outputs, three broad and one thin.

I've did search as 'overflow' tube but wasn't able to find many like this in Google Images, for the proof of concept.

Do you know how is called a similar piece like this but with two outputs and another output being this extra (thin pipe)?

Aditionally, if you do know, would you say what is the name of this 'double siphon with extra pipe' in portuguese, to me search in the Mercado Livre website?

Comment: It's an overflow tube to handle the overflow opening in the sink.

Comment: @vidarlo Do you know how is called this same piece but with two large outputs and one of these thin outputs? Triple siphon with overflow or whatever.

Comment: I think the best suggestion I have is to look at [this model from Ikea](https://www.ikea.com/pt/pt/p/lillviken-sifao-ralo-p-lava-loica-de-1-bacia-10311539/), which has documentation in Portuguese.

Comment: Thank you sir. I 'll take a look.

Comment: Was a good try, but it don't have a very expansible manual. I did take a look at the documentation but it have 99% images and didn't solve too much.

Comment: I'm sorry. I hope someone else can add a better answer :)

Comment: No problem. Gratitude

Comment: Technicality - only one of those it a "water output". The rest are all water *inputs*.

Comment: @brhans You're right

Comment: IKEA "documentation" is _never_ the answer to explain something - there are no words in any that I've ever seen. :(

Answer (score 1):

At least in the US, this drain "trap" assembly would often be assembled by attaching together multiple pieces to allow for all the input pipes you need. Connections can be glued (permanent) or "compression" or "slip joint" (removable).

The tube that attaches directly to the sink bottom drain hole is called a "tailpiece". In Portuguese it may be "conexão de prolongamento" although that may not be sink-specific. If it has extra inputs it is called a "branch" tailpiece.

I realize things seem to be at least a bit different in Portugal/Brazil(?) but I hope this helps.

Sample photo of US sink drain setup:

[image]